# How do I re-order discord channels according to number when I respond to the application?

Tags: typescript, discord.js

When someone applies for the server, A channel is created on the top of the server [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4knH7.png). But the order in which I respond to these applications is not consistent because of various different factors. When I respond to them, the channel is closed and moved to [a category Past Channels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N2zr.png). When I respond to the app and move it to the category, the channel just gets put on the top of the category channel list while I wanna order it according to the app number. How to do?

Among other things, this was the last thing I tried. It still didn't work. I am coding in typescript by the way.

```
function setPosition(client: myClient, channel: TextChannel) {
    const regex = /\d{4}$/;
    const appnum = Number(regex.exec(channel.name)![0]);
    console.log(`[SLASH COMMANDS] Application #${appnum} was responded to.`);
    const category = client.channels.cache.get(client.categoryPastApplications);
    if (!category || category.type !== ChannelType.GuildCategory) {
        console.log(
            `[SLASH COMMANDS] An error occured while executing command "application"! Code #6`
        );
        return;
    }
    const channelsCategory = category.children.cache.sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position);
    channelsCategory.forEach((categoryChannel) => {
        if (Number(regex.exec(categoryChannel.name)![0]) > appnum) {
            channel.setPosition(categoryChannel.position + 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Edit: I tried switching the function to this, but it still didn't work.

```
async function setPosition(client: myClient, channel: TextChannel) {
    const regex = /\d{4}$/;
    const appnum = Number(regex.exec(channel.name)![0]);
    console.log(`[SLASH COMMANDS] Application #${appnum} was responded to.`);
    const category = client.channels.cache.get(client.categoryPastApplications);
    if (!category || category.type !== ChannelType.GuildCategory) {
        console.log(
            `[SLASH COMMANDS] An error occured while executing command "application"! Code #6`
        );
        return;
    }
    const channelsCategory = category.children.cache.sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position);
    Object.values(channelsCategory).forEach(async (categoryChannel, index) => {
        if (Number(regex.exec(categoryChannel.name)![0]) < appnum) {
            await channel.setPosition(index + 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to sort the channels based on their number? If all the channels follow the same format, then try this one out.

```js
//Don't forget to place the code in an async function for await to work.

const category = client.channels.cache.get(client.categoryPastApplications);
let toSortArr = [];
let elements = category.children.cache.forEach((channel) => {
    let channelName = channel.name.substring(channel.name.indexOf("app"));
                
    toSortArr.push(channelName);
});
let sort = toSortArr.sort();

for (let [channelId, channel] of category.children.cache) {
    let channelName = channel.name.substring(channel.name.indexOf("app"));
    let index = sort.indexOf(channelName);

    await channel.setPosition(index);
}
```

Also avoid using forEach for async methods like async/await, since forEach is inherently synchronous. Use a regular for loop or like in the example I gave above, for of.